# How to set different dynamic IP address for each QEMU VM?

Tags: networking, debian, qemu, ipv4, libvirt

(Warning, предупреждение, попередження, avertissement (and whatever your language is): English is not my primary language. I wrote this through a translator).

I need to run about 7 virtual machines via QEMU. Each virtual machine runs Debian and has Steam in auto start. The goal of this is to run a particular game from a different account's on each of these machines.

The problems start as soon as each of the virtual machines tries to log into the steam account. It just gives a login error everywhere.

As it turns out, if you type "what is my IP" into google, it will show the same address on both the host and the virtual machine.

I decided to do a test - ran two virtual machines at the same time. In the first one everything as usual, in the second I enabled wireguard as a vpn. In the end, this test went perfectly: all two machines were able to log into their accounts.

Now a question: is it possible to give a random public address to each of the machines?

Comment: so, `ip a` shows the same IP address for all of them? Do you have enough "public" IP addresses for them to have a unique one?

Comment: @jaromanda-x, That's not what I meant. If you google "what is my ip" they have the same address. I'm not very good at networking, so I don't know if it's possible to assign a different address to each machine

Comment: You don't need a unique public IP for each qemu instance because it's normal that multiple PCs share one public IPv4 address.

Comment: @peregrino69, done. I think this counts.

Answer (score 0):

Giving random public IPs to different systems isn't possible. IP addresses are managed by [IANA](https://www.iana.org/). They've been assigned as blocks for local entities, who further assign them locally.

For example a local ISP has been assigned address range 203.0.113.0/24. They provide IP addresses for their customers, and it's assigned to the customer's internet-facing router, such as yours.

The LAN IP address range your router uses is most likely 192.168.1.0/24, i.e. every system in your local network has an unique IP in this range. When they access the Internet, the router performs NAT. As a result every system in your local network appears to the internet with the same IP address - your router's.

The only way you can get more public IP addresses is contracting them from your ISP.

The problem with logins isn't your IP. As I'm writing this, I'm logged on to my Steam account from my Debian laptop and 2 Debian VMs running on it, MacBook and a Windows laptop. No Wireguard or other tricks, just Steam client. As everything runs through the same router, all 5 systems connect to the internet with one single public IP address.